# Arrays not sorting properly in python

Tags: python, arrays, sorting

When I Try to use the sorted() function in python it only sorts the elements within each array alphabetically as the first 3 outputs are:

```
[u'A', u'a', u'a', u'f', u'g', u'h', u'i', u'n', u'n', u's', u't']
[u'N', u'a', u'e', u'g', u'i', u'i', u'r']
[u'C', u'a', u'e', u'm', u'n', u'o', u'o', u'r']
```

These should be Afghanistan, Nigeria and Cameroon respectively but instead they are only sorted within their own array.

Where have I went wrong in my code?

```
import urllib2
import csv
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ongoing_armed_conflicts"
soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen(url))

#f= csv.writer(open("test.csv","w"))
#f.writerow(["location"])
def unique(countries):
    seen = set()
    for country in countries:
        l = country.lower()
        if l in seen:
            continue
        seen.add(l)
        yield country



for row in soup.select('table.wikitable tr'):
    cells = row.find_all('td')
    if cells:
        for location in cells[3].find_all(text=True):
            location = location.split()

            for locations in unique(location):
                print sorted(locations)

#f.writerow([location])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With each iteration of the loop, you can get one or more locations (as a list). All of them need to be added to a single list to be able to sort it.

We use the `extend` method to do that.

```
locs = []  # contains all locations
for row in soup.select('table.wikitable tr'):
    cells = row.find_all('td')
    if cells:
        # location here returns a list
        for location in cells[3].find_all(text=True):
            locs.extend(location.split())

print sorted(locs)
```

`sorted(locs)` will also be a list. To print a specific element you can do

```
specific_element = sorted(locs)[index]
```

Comment: thanks this is exactly what I needed! How would I then select the fully iterated string? I've tried to print only specific elements but to no avail since print sorted(locs[any number]) says its out of range

Comment: I have updated my answer. `sorted` takes a list, but `locs[index]` will give you one element. To get element out of the sorted list you must do `sorted(locs)[index]`.

Comment: So when I do this I get a lot of [ ] values then after a while it comes up the first name then eventually all the names, how would I select the very last iterable?

Comment: To get the last sorted location? `sorted(locs)[-1]`. Negative indexing selects elements starting from the end of the list.

Answer (score 1):

Your variable names are bad, and are confusing you. `location` is a list of locations, and `locations` is a single location!

you want:

```
for locations in cells[3].find_all(text=True):
    locations = locations.split()

    for location in sorted(unique(locations)):
        print location
```